# Android - display time zone abbreviation (e.g., EST) for GMT offset

Tags: android, timezone, offset

I'm provided a time zone offset by a remote server (e.g., "GMT-08:00").  There doesn't seem to be a straight forward way of converting this value to its time zone abbreviation: "PST". This is NOT the same time zone as the device locale.  Has anyone dealt with this?

EDIT: I also have available other associated location information (e.g., lat/long, address)